# Why does overriding the WPF Window.OnRender method fail to draw to the screen?

Tags: wpf

I noticed that when overriding the System.Windows.Window OnRender method fails to draw to the screen. I'm sure there's a good reason for this but was unable to find the explanation.

The following code demonstrates this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        Pen pen = new Pen();

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            pen.Brush = Brushes.Black;
        }

        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
        {
            base.OnRender(dc);
            dc.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Black, pen, new Rect(0, 0, 600, 400));
            dc.DrawEllipse(Brushes.Green, pen, new Point(300, 300), 50, 50);
        }
    }
}
```

replacing the drawing logic in a FrameworkElement (then setting the element as the content of a window) work fine.

thanks,

Danny

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer is given by Chales Petzold [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/750e91c2-c370-4f0a-b18e-892afd99bd9b).

His answer is 'don't know why', however a comment correctly suggests that setting the window's Background to transparent fixes the bug.

Comment: "don't know why" doesn't really answer the question, and this fix doesn't work for ItemsControl derivatives which are using MVVM

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the Window paints itself, which among others is a rectangle for the background. Whatever is added in the OnRender is behind the background. Make the Background transparent and one can see what is behind it.

At least that is what I found out when using Button and OnRender. If I draw only within the button, nothing can be seen, because the button is drawn over it. But if the drawing extends beyond the button boundaries, anything outside can be seen.

[image]

Here an empty button is drawn over a yellow background. In the OnRender, I draw 2 black lines forming a cross. But only the parts of the line outside the button can be seen.

Very strange behavior of OnRender, indeed !

Answer (score 0):

just as a check, does the snippet work with the `dc.Draw...` lines removed (i.e. is it the act of overriding or the additional draw commands that cause the issue)?

I found a link that suggests that simply re-ordering the calls may solve the issue (i.e. doing the `dc.Draw...` calls before calling `base.OnRender(dc)`).

http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/3356653/Override-OnRender-class-inherits-frameworkelement.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think, that Grid generate this problem. Becouse by default Window contains Grid element